# How to get top 5 items for each group in grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weekday':list('MMMMMMMMMMTTTTTTTTTT'),
                  'Items': list("AAABBCDEFGBBBCCADEFG")
                  })

grouped = df.groupby(['Weekday','Items'],sort=True).agg({'Items': 'count'})
```

Then, I get the result of grouped:

```
Weekday Items       
M       A          3
        B          2
        C          1
        D          1
        E          1
        F          1
        G          1
T       A          1
        B          3
        C          2
        D          1
        E          1
        F          1
        G          1
```

So how to output the top 5 items for each "weekdays" (5 for 'M' and 'T'), like:

```
Weekday Items       
M       A          3
        B          2
        C          1
        D          1
        E          1

T
        B          3
        C          2
        A          1
        D          1
        E          1
```

Anyone can help this?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? See: [tour], [ask], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weekday':list('MMMMMMMMMMTTTTTTTTTT'),
              'Item': list("AAABBCDEFGBBBCCADEFG")
              })

grouped = df.groupby(['Weekday','Item'],sort=True).agg(count=('Item', 'count'))

grouped.sort_values(['Weekday','count'],ascending=False).groupby('Weekday').head(5)


           count
Weekday Item    
   T    B   3
        C   2
        A   1
        D   1
        E   1
    M   A   3
        B   2
        C   1
        D   1
        E   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 grouped = (df.groupby(['Weekday','Items'])
            .Items.agg(counter='count')
            .groupby(['Weekday'],
            as_index=False))

pd.concat([group.nlargest(5,'counter') for name,group in grouped])

              counter
Weekday Items   
M       A       3
        B       2
        C       1
        D       1
        E       1
T       B       3
        C       2
        A       1
        D       1
        E       1
```

groupby twice, first to get the counter variable. the second groupby allows an iteration through the groups to get the top 5, using nlargest. last step is to combine the dataframes in the list into one.

vb_rise's solution should be faster as it avoids the iteration process.